# A way to filter out parseonly statements from extended events?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I'm currently using extended events to capture query statements executed in a production environment. But the actual session is also capturing the activity of 'query parsing' done by operators to evaluate if a query is well written.

I would like to have an example of how to filter out SSMS activity of query parsing (CTRL+F5). This is used in production to check code. Ideally, code would be checked before production, but they are doing and willing to do it.

We have in place an XE solution that is working well but we need to fix a few 'human cases' like the `parseonly` queries.

An example of a session capturing a SQL text:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Session]
    ON SERVER
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed
    (
        ACTION(sqlserver.sql_text)
    )
    ADD TARGET package0.event_file
    (SET
        filename = N'C:\Folder\File.xel',
        max_file_size = (2),
        max_rollover_files = (2)
    )
    WITH (
        MAX_MEMORY = 2048 KB,
        EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = ALLOW_MULTIPLE_EVENT_LOSS,
        MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 3 SECONDS,
        MAX_EVENT_SIZE = 0 KB,
        MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE = NONE,
        TRACK_CAUSALITY = OFF,
        STARTUP_STATE = ON
    );
GO
```

I have no fixed starting session to fix. I would like an example of XE filtering out `parseonly` queries.

We cannot filter out the events using `host_name` or `client_app_name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use the more specific `sql_statement_completed` or `sp_statement_completed` which are not fired on query parsing.

If that's not an option, you can add additional filters to the `sql_batch_completed` event.

```sql
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Session] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed
(
    ACTION(sqlserver.sql_text)
    )
)
WHERE NOT
(
    row_count = 0
    AND logical_reads = 0
    AND writes = 0
)
```

Since the parse-only query is not executed, it will have no activity. The downside is that you might filter out other valid batches like `RAISERROR ('Custom error', 1,1)`.

Comment: Thank you. I will check them all. Probably fitering out error statemts is not an option as we also want to collect statements not allowed by rights.

Comment: It seems that using sql_statement_completed and sp_statement_completed make the day. I'm have to check the whole solution to evaluate if this change don't go to loose anithing else.